# ASP.NET MVC 3 Save lat and long from Google Map

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, google-maps

I have a Google Map on my View.

I wish to save the long and lat of the marker that has just recently been added to the Map.
My ViewModel has a Location object which contains a lat and long.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

The following is the code:

```
function addMarker(location, isdragable) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: _gmMap,
    icon: '../../Content/images/pin-red_32.png',
    draggable: isdragable
    });
$('#mainPlaceHolder_hdnlatlong').val(location.lat() + ',' + location.lng());
markersArray.push(marker);
if (isdragable) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
    showLocation(marker.getPosition().lat() + ',' + marker.getPosition().lng(), true);
    });
}
$('#spmsg').hide();
}
```

Comment: I can easily do the server-side code. I'm just confused on how to call the action method when the marker has been successfully placed on the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that "Save" is supposed to happen on the server, you need to make a request to the server. One way of doing this is to use jQuery's ajax method:

client-side javascript (replace <...> to fit your need):

```
function saveLocation()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "<Controller>/<Action>",
        data: <serializable form of your Location values>,
        dataType: "json",
        success: <callback>
    });
}
```